# Visual Studio Code debug not showing gear?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am having a small problem accessing the debugger in visual studio code. Specifically for PHP. I have downloaded this debug extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug

I have followed those instructions as well as other ones for various other languages. But they always have an instruction like "go to the debugger and hit the little gear icon and choose PHP".

However, no matter what I do this gear icon is just not present
[image]

It should be next to the little green 'play' button. I can't seem to figure out why it's not showing up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I reread the docs a little closer, it looks like *my answer* was a little off :)

VS Code can be used with single files, or with a directory as a workspace.
Within the Debug view, if you only have single files, you'll only get the green "play arrow", and VS Code will try it's best to debug the file (that's where you're at now).

To get the gear icon, you'll need to open the workspace directory of the file(s) you want to debug (and this is where you want to be).

<strike>It seems like the documentation you're reading is a little off (maybe it was written to a previous version?).</strike>

That gear icon is editing an existing `launch.json` [Launch Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations), which you don't have yet (because you're trying to make one :).

If you hit the play icon/green arrow, you'll open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) menu you're expecting to see, which will give you a selection of mostly complete `launch.json` templates for the language and/or toolchain you picked in the Command Palette menu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something silly I was missing. Sorry about my confusion. Thank you for your help!